# SSRS and SQL NTILE won't accept parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, quantile

I am using SSRS Report Builder 3.0 and I have put together a report, part of which uses a query that pulls in data and separates it into different summary rows using the NTILE() function in SQL. That's all working fine and dandy, but boss now wants me to add a parameter to decide whether the report should pull quartiles, quintiles, deciles, etc. and so I figured I would just create a parameter to pass an integer to the NTILE(@ntiles) function, and that would be a piece of cake.

Problem is, I've created my parameter, it is an INT and passes a value like (2,3,4,5,6,10) and linked it to my query in Report Builder, but when I save the query with NTILE(@ntiles) (I named my parameter @ntiles) it throws an error:

`The function 'ntile' takes only a positive int or bigint expression as its input.`

The funny thing is, the report will still run, and correctly as if the parameter works, but I have no idea why it's throwing this error and pretending like it's not going to work. Google didn't really turn anything up on this issue; is it a bug with Report Builder 3.0 or am I doing something wrong? How can I make the error go away? Thanks.

EDIT: Trying NTILE(CAST(@ntiles as INT)) threw the same error, and then broke the query so that the report would not run. Weirdly enough, just changing it back to NTILE(@ntiles) left it still broken; workaround was to change it to a real INT like NTILE(4), reload the query, then go back and change it to NTILE(@ntiles). It still throws the error when you save it, but it does not prevent the report from running with that workaround.

Comment: Can you try to add an explicit CAST(@ntiles as Int) inside of your query and see if it changes anything?

Comment: You say "it is an INT and passes a value like (2,3,4,5,6,10) ". But "(1,2,3,4,5,6,10)" is not an INT.  Exactly what value are you passing?

Comment: @GandRalph Sorry, that was confusing. The parameter type is explicitly INT, and the values (options) it was are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 10

Comment: @Ian-Fogelman That seemed like a good idea to try, weirdly enough it threw the same error but also actually broke the query. I think this must just be SSRS quirkiness.

Comment: It sounds like you have not defined a parameter on the dataset assigned to the ntiles report parameter? When it executes it is not replaceing the @ntile with the value you specify.

Comment: How is the parameter setup in SSRS, what datatype? Might sound counter-intuitive but if you have it set as an integer, try changing it back to the default text (or the other way round)